# Serializing a form using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm sending data in two parts through ajax:

```
data: {
    imageData: ctx.imageData,
    formData: $("#content-add-form").serialize()
},
```

`imageData` is base 64 encoded images, these are then resized and saved using a PHP script.

`formData` is all of the form fields. The problem is, it's coming out at the other end as:

```
title=my+title&date=16-09-2013
```

How can I send it so each field is an array? And also use the `serialize()` method?

Answer (score 1):

You can use serialize. Below is an example.

```
$("#submit_btn").click(function(){
    $('.error_status').html();
        if($("form#frm_message_board").valid())
        {
            $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "<?php echo site_url('message_board/add');?>",
                  data: $('#frm_message_board').serialize(),
                  success: function(msg) {
                      var msg = $.parseJSON(msg);
                      if(msg.success=='yes')
                      {
                                                                        return true;
                     }
                     else
                     {
                        alert('Server error');
                        return false;
                    }
                   }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: You can send your data in json format.Use json_encode function and send data as a string.

Comment: That won;t work either because json encode is a php function not a js one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.serializeArray()](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/).